# Countifs using multiple dynamic arrays as criteria

Tags: excel-formula

I have a countifs formula that seems to be letting me down.

It's using 2 different criteria and both are dynamic arrays - here represented by the cell ref and the hashtag:

```
COUNTIFS(A:A,B1#,C:C,D1#)
```

The dynamic arrays in cells B1 and D1 are working fine, and if I change the countifs so only 1 of the criteria refers to a dynamic range (removing the hashtag and selecting 1 of the results in the array) then it works fine. The problem is when I need it to use 2 (or more?) dynamic ranges.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the items are independent of each other as in B1 does not directly correlate to D1 and B2 directly correlates to D2 then you need to Transpose one of the arrays.

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,B1#,C:C,TRANSPOSE(D1#))
```

Note:

This will create a 2D array with as many rows as in B1# and as many Columns as in D1#.  So to get the total wrap it in SUM or SUMPRODUCT.

Also, The max independent arrays are two.

Also that it is an AND situation so the value in A must be equal to the a value in B and the value in C in the same row, must be equal to a value in D

[image]

If one wants more than two we need to move away from countifs and use array type formula which will require the use of ranges that encompass the most rows that would be used and not full columns.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1:A100,B1#,0))*ISNUMBER(MATCH(C1:C100,D1#,0)))
```

This version is AND like the COUNTIFS where the values in A and C on the same row must exist their corresponding lists to be counted.  IF you want to count them individually then change the `*` to `+` which makes it an OR.

And the use of `ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1:A100,B1#,0))` can be added as many as desired changing the ranges as necessary.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the info, not only did you answer my question you went above and beyond to explain it further, brilliant!

Answer (score 0):

Edit: This will not work, see below comment by @Scott Craner

I'm unsure if `COUNTIFS` work well with dynamic arrays, which is what you are currently using.

A workaround can be to try use `SUMPRODUCT`

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A:A=B1#)*(C:C=D1#))
```

Comment: This will not work if B1# and D1# do not fill the whole column or B1# AND D1# would need to be single cell arrays.  All four would need to be the same size and shape and it would be row by row comparison. as in B1 would need to equal A1 and D1 would need to equal C1 to count.  Then it would move to row two and B2 would need to equal A2 and D2 would need to equal C2 to count.